# How to convert json object to dates?

Tags: javascript, flatpickr

I am using [flatpicker](https://flatpickr.js.org/) **range** and `onChange` I do:

```
onChange: function(dateObj, dateStr) {
  console.info(dateObj, dateStr);
```

That gives me in console:

```
0: Tue Mar 10 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (Ora standard dell’Europa centrale) {}
1: Thu Mar 12 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (Ora standard dell’Europa centrale) {}
```

But I am not sure how to convert that to `d m Y`

Looking for this format with no time or zone: `1/23/2020`

Something like:

```
var dateStart = new Date(data.from);
var dateEnd = new Date(data.to);
dateStart.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
dateEnd.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString

Comment: @Phix thanks checking

Comment: Can't you use the flatpicker's `dateFormat` option for that ?

Comment: @Titus yes if I'd only could find it! Do you have a link?

Comment: You can find details about this option [HERE](https://flatpickr.js.org/options/)

Comment: @Titus Ok I now just gave dateFormat: "d-m-Y",  but when I console I get the same result as per the question. What am I doing wrong on console?

Comment: @Titus note I am using a range

Comment: In that case, the `dateStr` argument will look something like this: `10-03-2020 to 19-03-2020`. To get an array of strings formatted as you want, you can use `var datesArr = dateStr.split(" to ")`

Comment: @Titus By doing that i only get one value and not d-m-Y but ["2020-03-10"]

Comment: @Titus ok works, thanks, put that into an answer and I'll accept it

Comment: I've posted an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flatpicker has an option for specifying the format (`dateFormat`), in your case, since you're working with ranges, the second argument to the `onChange` callback will have this format: `[date value] to [date value]`, to create a dates array in the required format from this string, you can use `secondArgument.split(' to ')`, here is an example:

```js
flatpickr("#dateInput", {
  mode: "range",
  dateFormat: "d/m/Y",
  onChange: (_, dateRangeStr) => {
    const datesStrArr = dateRangeStr.split(" to ");
    console.log(datesStrArr);
  }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/flatpickr/dist/flatpickr.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/flatpickr"></script>
<input id="dateInput" />
```